# How to deal with Resource-waiting in RAII

Tags: c++, raii

I'm new to C++, and I'm currently learning the RAII (Resource Acquisition is Initialization) pattern.
I was curious how one would deal with resources that they needed to wait on.

In Java, something that might be done is:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
new Thread(
    () -> obj.initialize(); // resource acquisition
).start()

...

if (obj.initialized()) {
    // Use object
}
```

In other words, we can perform a time-intensive resource-acquisition in the background.

How can we do that in C++, with RAII? Or is this a limitation with RAII?

Comment: You should really add a complete example. Java and C++ are different languages, and answer probably depends on context.

Comment: I don't see how `RAII` comes into it? It looks like you are looking for the `future` pattern

Comment: You can not possibly hope for simple answer to dim question about concurrency? There are piles of scientific publications on the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RAII means that resources are defined by some object. Ideally, the constructor of that object gets the resource, and the destructor releases it. During the time when the object is valid, you can use the object to interact with the resource.

If a resource "needs to be waited on", then by the rules of RAII, that means you don't have an object that represents that resource *yet*. You instead have an object that represents a resource that will be available in the future.

Which is why C++ calls this type `std::future`. It's a template, with the argument being the type of the object whose creation you are waiting on.

Conceptually, a `future` is just a means to forward an object (or exception) from the piece of code that generates it (possibly asynchronously) to the receiver.

Now given your example, we need to remove `initialize` from `MyClass` and make that a function which *returns* a `MyClass` instance. It could be a static member of `MyClass`, or it could be just a namespace-scoped function.

So the code would essentially look like this:

```
auto future = std::async(initialize);

...

if(future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready)
{
  MyClass resource = future.get(); //The `future` is now empty. Any exceptions will be thrown here.

  //use resource
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, I wasn't aware C++ had the same concept of future, but I think this addresses my concern perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

RAII addresses an antipattern when it's possible to obtain an object that is not yet ready for use. In particular, your Java code suffers from the same antipattern - it's easy for a user of `MyClass` to forget to run the `initialize` method immediately after constructing the object.

The easiest way to enforce RAII when complex initialization needs to happen is via a factory method. Make the potentially unsafe constructor private and expose a public static function that will construct *and* initialize the object for you. In particular, if you want to run the initialization concurrently, there is nothing stopping you from making the return type of that factory method into an `std::future` or similar.

The key takeway is the purpose of RAII - it must not be possible to acquire a resource that is not initialized. By making the only way to acquire into a function that always initializes the resource, you get RAII.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't know C++ had something like future<>, but that would definitely solve the problem here, thanks! I only put the Threaded #initialize in this post, since I thought C++ would have to do something similar.